# Is it "when he's massaging me" or "while he's massaging me" : which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence: "when he's massaging me, I'm wondering about you."  Is the "when" correct or instead of "when" should I use "while"? Or are both correct for the context?

Comment: @tchrist:  I don't understand the duplicate link.  I need an explanation on my particular situation.

Comment: Yes they are both correct. The duplicate @tchrist linked to gives a nice explanation of how the two forms differ and when each should be used.

Comment: @verve Do you actually mean to talk about someone "massaging" you? Or "messaging" you? I hope you know the difference. (p.s.: I have not yet heard about any guy "massaging".)

Comment: @ShaonaBose I don't understand your *p.s.*. Do you mean you haven't heard of "massaging", or do you mean that you haven't heard of a "guy" doing it. If the latter, I assume you mean a male person, but "guy" can also include females, so is a bad choice of word. And it's not unusual to see male masseurs in films, etc..

Comment: Okay, I should not have added that post script.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be used with little difference in meaning. *When* emphasizes on the action, while *while* emphasizes on its duration.

Answer (score 0):

They're pretty much the same, although 'while' seems to emphasise the simultaneous nature of that next clause (I'm wondering...) and its strong relationship with the act of massaging.